# How to stop the propagation of keyup events in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

I am trying make an input field that takes only numbers and allows decimal values up to 2 decimal places. I want to stop the user inputs on the field after 2 decimal places. So that whatever the user enters, the value would not be entered. I am using `keyup` event because `keypress` actually takes the value late so that creates a problem with the checking. In the HTML I'm using:

```
<input
formControlName="WorkhoursPerWeek"    
class="mon-input-num"
(keyup)="validateNumber($event)"                                   
 />
```

In the Typescript the function goes as:

```
validateNumber(event: Event): Boolean {
    const DECIMAL_PLACES_REGEX = /^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/;
    if (!DECIMAL_PLACES_REGEX.test(event.target["value"])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to the user entry on the `keyup` function by using `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`. Any ideas on how I can stop the user field entry?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, your check is too late.

The simplest way to solve this is as follows:

NOTE: WorkhoursPerWeek should really be camelCase as workhoursPerWeek

```
validateNumber(event: Event): Boolean {
    const DECIMAL_PLACES_REGEX = /^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/;
    if (!DECIMAL_PLACES_REGEX.test(event.target["value"])) {
        let myValue = this.form.controls.WorkhoursPerWeek.value;
        myValue = myValue.substring(0, myValue.length-1);
        this.form.controls.WorkhoursPerWeek.setValue(myValue);
    }
}
```